# Publish an app under a different PlayStore account than the project and api key is created under

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

is it possible to publish an app under one PlayStore account if the project and api key is created under another Developer account ? Billing is enabled on the latter.

I don't have an option to run trial and error.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to publish an app in different play store account even if your app has some other account api keys in it. Just for confirmation the api keys you are referring here is Google API's key right?

Comment: Yes, for Google Maps and other services. But some of the API needs billing enabled like Google Maps Geolocation API. So, when this service is used the account that was used to generate the api keys will be billed, am I right ?

Comment: By default, there will be some limitation for all google services.https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/usage . You can refer that link. Maximum there will be free of cost for 1000 hits per day for each api's . If you feel that will exit across it we need to purchase it. Also, in this case also, we can have account for Play store account and Developer console account. There will be no problem in it.